# Separate thread for compressing logfiles in Logback?

Tags: java, performance, logging, logback

In Logback, we could config as: 1 when the size of the logfile reaches like 50MB, rotate the file and compress it. So I wonder will it do the compress stuff in a separate thread, will it have any performance issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have investigated logback-1.0.3.
Let's consider use case:

1. You invoke [Logger#error(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.error%28java.lang.String%29) in your code.
2. Your data [filtered](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus%28java.lang.String%2Corg.slf4j.Marker%2Cch.qos.logback.classic.Level%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29) according Logger configuration.
3. Will invoke [Appenders](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/AppenderAttachableImpl.java#AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders%28java.lang.Object%29) after [buildLoggingEventAndAppend](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend%28java.lang.String%2Corg.slf4j.Marker%2Cch.qos.logback.classic.Level%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29) and [callApenders](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.callAppenders%28ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent%29)
4. In your case will invoke append method in [OutputStreamAppender](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/core/OutputStreamAppender.java#OutputStreamAppender.append%28java.lang.Object%29).
5. Trigger based [RollingFileAppender](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.java#RollingFileAppender.subAppend%28java.lang.Object%29) will invoke [rollover](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.java#FixedWindowRollingPolicy.rollover%28%29) when event triggered.
6. In rollover method will invoke [appropriate compress method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.3/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/Compressor.java#Compressor.compress%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

As you can see all stuff will be logged and compressed in the same thread as data logged. And thus you shouldn't log in time critical threads.

Personally, I suppose logging in the same thread is not critical for majority applications, but it depends strongly from your environment, perfomance requirements, e.t.c.

If you want to log data asynchronously you can use [AsyncAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender). In this case compressing also will be in separate thread.

Comment: Maybe one of possible solutions for compress method called in the same thread as data logged would be to use an async appender between...

Comment: @AdamDyga you are right. It is legal workaround for this problem.

Comment: The logback doc says that the async appender uses a fixed-size blocking queue, and if the queue starts to fill up, as may happen while compressing a large file, it drops messages at INFO level and below (you can tune or disable this).  If the queue fills all the way up, the calling thread blocks, so the behavior becomes effectively synchronous again.  You may be able to tune the queue size and file size to avoid this.